# Mod rewrite 301 redirect https with www to https only

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to redirect,

> `https://www`

to https, but with no success.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^https://www.site.domain$
RewriteRule (.*)$ https://site.domain/ [R=301,L]
```

Here is what I've tried.

Answer (score 0):

`%{HTTP_HOST}` only matches host name without protocol `http://` or `https://`.

Use your rule like this in `DocumentRoot/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(ivon\.bg)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: it is still not redirecting the url

Comment: What URL didn't redirect and where is this .htaccess located?

Comment: htaccess is working, but the redirection from https:(//www.site).domain to https:(//site).domain is not working with the example you gave me.

Comment: What I asked was **where is this .htaccess located?** I know it might be working for you. Are there more rules in this .htaccess?